# Delete 1Bn records from a oracle warehouse table

Tags: oracle, exadata

I have a huge table created from another table by someone and want to delete it. I do not have truncate/drop table right. What would be the best solution. it is in oracle.

Right now i plan to give a simple `Delete * from table`

Comment: What is the problem with `delete from table` query?

Comment: @vipin cp : Deleting from 1Bn record  table would probably take hours, even with Exadata

Comment: @guigui42 Then request to give permission for truncate and perform it :) No other way.

Answer (score 0):

if DELETE takes too long for you, and you do no have permission to TRUNCATE or DROP table, then the only solution I see is to **Ask your DBA to do it for you** !

Answer (score 0):

Convert the table into a partitioned one, and drop the partition in question. The latter will take seconds.